# i want to write a function that rewrite a float to continued fraction

Tags: error-handling, f#

i am trying to make a recursive function, that can rewrite a float to an continued fraction. I am getting an error messange that i dont understand

it seems like it can't storage certain numbers binary and how do i compare then. Thats my current theory.

> condition 'cfa_reg != -1' not met

```
  let rec float2cfrac (x : float) : int list =
        if x - floor x = 0.0 then 
            [int x]
        else 
            [int x] @ float2cfrac (1.0/(x - floor x))

    printfn "%A" (float2cfrac 3.245)// list
```

Comment: What is the "error message that you don't understand"?

Answer (score 2):

When I run your code. I get a stack overflow.

That means that your condition `x - floor x = 0.0` is never met.

Equality with floating point numbers is a tricky thing as there is always a small precision error involved in all calculations. Never use equality, instead calculate until the difference is less than an acceptable error:

```
abs(x - floor x) < 0.0000000001
```